# Issue while enabling hyperlinks in master page from content page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had written code to Enable and disable hyperlinks on master page from the content page. Every thing is working fine and the hyperlinks are getting disabled also after calling the `DisableHyperlinkInMasterPage` Method. When i am calling the `EnableHyperlinkInMasterPage` method still the hyperlinks are not working. If we are leaving that page , then i found that the hyperlinks starts working. My issue is after calling the `EnableHyperlinkInMasterPage`  method , without leaving the page the hyperlinks are still disabled and not working and after leaving the page it getting enabled . Please help me that how i fix this issue.I debug the code and not found any error on `EnableHyperlinkInMasterPage` method.

```
private void DisableHyperlinkInMasterPage()
    {
        AssociateMaster mymaster = (AssociateMaster)Page.Master;
        HyperLink home = (HyperLink)mymaster.FindControl("Home");
        home.Enabled = false;
        HyperLink profile = (HyperLink)mymaster.FindControl("ProfileLink");
        profile.Enabled = false;
        HyperLink report = (HyperLink)mymaster.FindControl("Report");
        report.Enabled = false;
        HyperLink signout = (HyperLink)mymaster.FindControl("SignOut");
        signout.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void EnableHyperlinkInMasterPage()
    {
        AssociateMaster mymaster = (AssociateMaster)Page.Master;
        HyperLink home = (HyperLink)mymaster.FindControl("Home");
        home.Enabled = true;
        HyperLink profile = (HyperLink)mymaster.FindControl("ProfileLink");
        profile.Enabled = true;
        HyperLink report = (HyperLink)mymaster.FindControl("Report");
        report.Enabled = true;
        HyperLink signout = (HyperLink)mymaster.FindControl("SignOut");
        signout.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: Your code inside EnableHyperlinkInMasterPage() seems alright. At what point in the page lifecycle are you calling this method?

Comment: Do you get a NullRefernceException? Why don't you provide the (public) method in the MasterPage itself instead of in every content page?

Comment: @Edwin de Koning- I am calling this method after Content page load.

Comment: @Tim-  i am not getting any error as i had added <%@ MasterType virtualpath="~/AssociateMaster .Master"%> , i think if we refresh the master page after calling this content page, or render the controls of master page then the issue may fix.

Comment: Even if you'd add a virtual path you could have provided wrong ID's or `NamingContainers` to find the `HyperLinks`. What means _"**after** page_load exactly"_? You haven't answered why you didn't simply add the method to your MasterPage instead of every ContentPaage.

Comment: @Tim, I am providing correct ID's of the hyperlinks. When the page load all the hyperlinks are working fine and after certain calculation as per my requirement , I am disabling it so that the user cant leave this page. After calling DisableHyperlinkInMasterPage all the links get disabled and after that when user fullfills the requirement , i am calling EnableHyperlinkInMasterPage. I had not created public method in masterpage because this functionality, i want in only this page. No where i am doing this in the entire project.

Comment: The method in masterpage would have three big advantages: reusing(obsolete), compile time checking because you could write `ProfileLink.Enabled=false`,Less prone of errors if you change it in future(add,rename or remove links).

Answer (score 1):

Try using properties to enable and disable links. And try using FindControl as less as you can. Consider you have a link in your MasterPage named lnkTest. Write this code in your master page:

```
 public bool TestLinkEnabled
 {
      get { return lnkTest.Enabled; }
      set {lnkTest.Enabled = value; }
 }
```

Then in your content page after adding this line to your page:

```
 <%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPage.master" %>
```

enable and disable this link using:

```
  Master.TestLinkEnabled = true;
  Master.TestLinkEnabled = false;
```